# Create a OneNote plug-in with VB6

Tags: vb6, add-in, onenote

First of all, I tried to make a very simple plug-in with VB6 for OneNote 2010 / 2013.

I wrote similar plug-ins for Excel and Word and I peeled off everything unnecessary.

But basically the plug-on was this in the Connect.Dsr file:

```
Option Explicit

Dim ONApp As OneNote14.Application

Private Sub AddinInstance_OnConnection(ByVal Application As Object, ByVal ConnectMode As AddInDesignerObjects.ext_ConnectMode, ByVal AddInInst As Object, custom() As Variant)
Set ONApp = Application
MsgBox "Conned"
End Sub

Private Sub AddinInstance_OnDisconnection(ByVal RemoveMode As AddInDesignerObjects.ext_DisconnectMode, custom() As Variant)
MsgBox "DISCONN"
End Sub
```

I'd did every necessary modifications in the .dsr file such us:

```
AppName         =   "Microsoft OneNote"
AppVer          =   "Microsoft OneNote 14.0"
LoadName        =   "Startup"
LoadBehavior    =   3
RegLocation     =   "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\OneNote"
```

These are needed for proper operation.

The trick was the follow: while I was running it in the VB6 IDE, it was working well. But when I compiled it to .dll, the OneNote COM add-in handler said it can't load plug-on because of runtime error.

Crazy, not?

Comment: You may also make an answer out of your comment. Just fill the form below))

Comment: After some 8 hours of trial, I finally ended up with the solution: **YOU NEED TO COMPILE THE CODE TO .EXE, NOT .DLL !!!!!** That was all needed for proper operation! Any other complexities like missing registry entries or any othe specialty was unnecessary.

Comment: I mean the BIG FORM below which is below the words "Your Answer" :)

Comment: As a guess to explain the "why" of your answer: *If* you were using a x64 build of OneNote then it is expected that trying to load an in-process (DLL) x86 plugin would fail, thus the need to implement your plugin as a COM server instead.